# Extract Part of Sentence from Text File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, token

I have an awkward text file (hosts.txt) I need to extract a certain part of a sentence from:-

```
18 Jul 2019 09:30 BST
62.172.169.12
United Kingdom 
H82640A745.XGPH82640
3.12.21.0
Remove
18 Jul 2019 09:29 BST
62.172.169.9
United Kingdom 
H82640A744.XGPH82640
3.12.21.0
Remove
18 Jul 2019 09:26 BST
62.172.169.18
United Kingdom 
H82640A740.XGPH82640
3.12.21.0
Remove
```

I just need the H*********  number next to .XGPH82640 - so from the example I just need a list like:-

```
H82640A745
H82640A744
H82640A740
```

and so on...

I am trying to extract using tokens and delims in batch but I'm not getting any where. If I try and Skip=X number of lines it doesn't work because the first H******* number has three lines above, but from then on has 5.

I have read the SS64 on tokens and delims as I would really like to be able to figure this out myself but I'm not getting it. Especially with this text file.

At the minute I am trying to use the ":" as the delimiter but again the token numbers alter, so if it was just the first five lines

```
For /F "Tokens=4 delims=:" %%A In (hosts.txt) Do echo %%A
```

Any help would be great - thanks!

Comment: `for /f "delims=." %%A in ('findstr /EC:".XGPH82640" hosts.txt') Do Echo %%A`

Comment: …or similarly: `@(If Exist "hosts.txt" For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /LIE ".XGPH82640" "hosts.txt""')Do @Echo(%%~nA)&Pause`.

Comment: @Compo, nice one. Would also catch a prefix with additional dots. Combined: `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /EC:".XGPH82640" hosts.txt 2^>NUL') Do @Echo(%%~nA`

Comment: thanks! What would happen if the "XGPH82640" became something else - as it will do but the format of the file will be the same - thanks

Comment: @Tika9o9, please see my answer for a potential solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based upon my comment and your subsequent suggestion that the lines may contain an unknown single period separated alphanumeric string instead of known one:

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "hosts.txt" GoTo :EOF
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    '""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /X "^[A-Z0-9]*\.[A-Z0-9]*$" "hosts.txt""'
) Do Echo %%~nA
Pause
```

Directly in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('""%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /X "^[A-Z0-9]*\.[A-Z0-9]*$" "hosts.txt" 2>NUL"')Do @Echo %~nA
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use following command line in your batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%I in (hosts.txt) do if "%%J" == "XGPH82640" echo %%I
```

**FOR** reads the file `hosts.txt` line by line with ignoring empty lines.

The string delimiter is modified with `delims=.` from default normal space or horizontal tab to character `.`.

Of interest for this task are lines which have two dot delimited substrings whereby the second substring should be `XGPH82640`. For that reason `tokens=1,2` is used to get first dot delimited string assigned to loop variable `I` and second dot delimited string assigned to next loop variable which is `J` according to [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

If the first substring after removing all leading `.` would start with a semicolon, command **FOR** would also ignore the line because of `eol=;` is the default for end of line character. But it can be assumed that no line with `XGPH82640` starts with `;` and therefore the default end of line character can be kept as is.

The case-sensitive **IF** condition verifies if the second dot delimited string is really `XGPH82640` and not an empty string as on the lines with date/time or with country and or a decimal number as on the lines with an IPv4 address.

On a true **IF** condition the first dot delimited string is output to console.